# Why can't my app connect to localhost with easyphp devserver?

Tags: android, localhost, emulation, easyphp, connectexception

I'm making an android app that retrieves informations from a web page.
In short, there's the code :

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(getHomeUrl() + "myPage.php");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
                doThings(conn);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }        
        return null;
   }
```

If the url is http://www.mywebsite.com/myPage.php, the connection is OK.
But if the url is http://localhost/myPage.php or http://127.0.0.1:80/myPage.php with easyphp devserver on, I catch an IOException and get this :

- on android emulator => java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
- on physical device (as deployment target) => java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

For information, when I copy paste http://127.0.0.1:80/myPage.php in my browser, the access is granted.

I read that android emulator could "use" localhost, and it is suggested to take 10.0.2.2 instead, but it didn't work either.
I guess this is a matter of apache conf, but I have this, that seems correct to me :

```
<Directory "D:/Utilitaires/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you started apache server?

Comment: `For information, when I copy paste http://127.0.0.1:80/myPage.php in my browser,` Yes... in the browser of your pc. But you should do that in the browser of your Android device or emulator. That will not go.

Comment: `Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Deny from all` Wrong. That would be connections which came from the same pc. Better: `Allow from all
        Deny from nobody`

Comment: 10.0.2.2  is ok using an emulator. Or the local ip-address of the server computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on your computer, so `127.0.0.1` is working only on that machine. If you would like to access it from your phone you should write your computer's local address (ie: `192.168.10.100`).  It will be working fine if your network is configured properly.

I recommend to you that upload your website to a public host and you can easily access it from your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !
It failed with http://10.0.2.2, but it's ok with http://10.0.2.2:80 !